# Stack Mobile - View Stack Exchange Sites on Your Smart Phone or Tablet

Tags: app, website

> ### Update:
>
> Stack Mobile is about to get a breath of fresh air. I've just moved it to a brand new server with a blazing fast SSD.
>
> **Note:** it may take up to a day or two for DNS changes to propagate.

### [stackmobile.com](http://stackmobile.com)

[image]

### Screenshot

[image]

### About

Stack Mobile is a mobile-friendly front-end to all of the sites in the Stack Exchange network. It has a number of handy features that make browsing the sites easy and hassle-free. Here are just a few of them:

- Full access to all questions, answers, comments, tags, and users on **all** Stack Exchange sites including ones that are in private beta.
- Full question, user, and tag search capability.
- The ability to easily switch between Stack Mobile and the equivalent page on the main site.
- View tags and tag wiki excerpts as well as questions with certain tags.
- View user profiles including a user's top five questions / answers.

#### License

Stack Mobile is released under the [GPLv3](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html).

#### Platform

The site should be accessible to virtually any phone browser.
I have tested with the following:

- Android 2.2
- webOS 1.4.1
- Opera Mini 6.5

*It was reported by a few of people that the site works perfectly on iPhone/iPad/iPod and BlackBerry. However, it is always nice to hear from people that the site displays fine on their phone.*

### Contact

Email me at admin@quickmediasolutions.com

### Code

The source code for Stack Mobile is available on GitHub:
https://github.com/nathan-osman/Stack-Mobile

Comment: I have now put the API key into place. Feel free to browse the site now.

Comment: You need to HTMLEncode the Title on this page:
http://m.stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/question_list.php

Comment: Very cool, somewhat curious though - in chrome the application seems happy to shrink-width all the way down to single-word, but in the android browser, it seems to have a min-width of about 2 portrait screens. I wish I could tell you why this is.

Comment: Nice. 1 suggestion - mobile apps should have short URL's.

Comment: @Dave: Thanks! It's always good to hear that the site works on phones that I don't have the resources to test.

Comment: @Techboy +1 Was just about the same thing. :)

Comment: I have added tags and badges now.

Comment: @sys: Thanks! Any suggestions for improvements? I'm already working on a new theme.

Comment: @George i would add pagination on search results

Comment: @sys: Don't worry. It's in the works :)

Comment: @George, nope, looks pretty good to me. Now bring on the v2 API - Read/Write :D

Comment: I have now implemented pagination for specific questions.

Comment: Looking good! I've incorporated your site into my Android widget now, thanks again!

Comment: BTW: iOS4 screenshot of this question: http://gallery.me.com/davedelong#100084/StackMobile&bgcolor=black

Comment: @Dave: Thanks! I might move things around a bit after seeing the screenshot... some things are getting to crowded together.

Comment: My iPhone 3G ended up in the bottom of a bucket of water last week (son's fault) so I reverted back to my oldschool Nokia N73. And the site looks... well... perfect! Great job!

Comment: this is beautiful, good work.

Comment: @BrandonClark: It's a web application. Just go to http://stackmobile.com on your PlayBook's web browser.

Comment: Working great on my playbook so far.

Comment: I'm getting API errors everywhere(Can't even select a site)

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS: Unfortunately the app has become too popular for its own good :P So many people are using it that it exceeds the rate limit for API requests and the API blocks the app for a few hours.

Comment: Is this app still supported?  I keep getting generic/unhelpful "An API error has occurred." pages. If it's still a quota thing (in addition to  the too vague messages), people have successfully requested and received extra quota for their apps. ... In view of `"Note: this project is no longer actively maintained."`, perhaps we should tag this obsolete, to reduce [disappointment and confusion](https://stackapps.com/q/8255).

Comment: 6 years late but I'm interested. as you are aware SE switched to responsive view and I really don't like it, I miss mobile view. I just came across this post and your GitHub. looks like the code is there but no app. also I see you haven't had any activity since like Jan 24th. what would make you come back and finish this app?

Answer (score 20):

[image: One margin is enough!]

One margin is enough!

The defining characteristic of mobile screens is that they are small; every pixel counts!  A design with two margins is wasteful (and also adds extra visual noise).

Comment: I'm saying there should only be one margin between the edge of the screen and the content.  (And yes, that one margin should be smaller than the sum of the existing two.)

Comment: I shrunk the margins quite a bit now.

Answer (score 4):

Would it be possible to replace the stackMobile logo with the current site's logo?

For example instead of putting stackMobile in the title bar:

[image]

replace that with the site's name:

[image]

Comment: I put the name of the site in the middle now.

Comment: @George: I like the change. It's a good compromise.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's interesting that a 3×3 grid is becoming a metaphor for "Home", but in cases like this where the home screen is not actually a 3×3 grid of buttons, I don't know if everyone will get it. You could just as easily put a "Home" button up there.

Comment: Well... actually the 3x3 grid is supposed to be StackMobile's logo and eventually will be replaced by a back button. I'm thinking of pointing the "StackMobile" header at the top to the home page.

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with codes in posts.

`Code` lines are not breaking and some part might not be visible - see missing parts here:
http://stackmobile.com/view_question.php?site=stackoverflow&id=316099

I'd suggest removing the css for post maxwidth and set width to paragraphs of text for reader's comfort, leaving out the `code`

Comment: What do you mean by set width to paragraphs of text?

Comment: Actually I think I know what you're talking about... the `<code>` section is getting clipped at the right side. This has been something I've tried to fix before, but it's a complex issue. It's not as simple as just removing the forced with of the block.

Comment: I think it's purely a CSS thing.  change width and overflow and if this isn't enough - use word-wrap

Comment: This may be fixed with the new version now.

Answer (score 1):

In a users profile the **top 5** questions/answers show the **latest 5** questions/answers instead.

[For example on my profile](http://stackmobile.com/meta.stackoverflow/users/172011).