# Clarification on StackApps "App" vs "Script"

Tags: discussion

Pursuant to a [chat conversation](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/conversation/app-or-script) there's some clarification needed on what it means for a [stackapp](http://stackapps.com) to be an app or a script. I'm posting this for the community and for future searchers and as a bit of a FAQ (sorta)

If you haven't heard about this, read Jeff's latest blog entry [Stack Apps and Scripts](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/stack-apps-and-scripts/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things that make you a [app](/questions/tagged/app)

- you do NOT run in a web browser
- you create a totally different user interface
- you are not written in JavaScript
- you are many thousands of lines of code, far too much to list in a Stack Overflow post or an average blog entry

Things that make you a [script](/questions/tagged/script)

- you run only in the web browser
- you make small modifications to the existing website user interface
- you are written in JavaScript
- your code is small enough to print in a Stack Overflow post or an average blog entry

This IMO is not so difficult to figure out.

Comment: Our little SEChatModifications may not fit in a SO Post tho :\ and it's definitely Javascript

Comment: @drachenstern, but it fits for everything else.  So the code is long, it does a lot of things!

Comment: Some apps run a in a webbrowser, eg http://stackapps.com/questions/36/. So i think your first point on app is not true.

Comment: @Jonathan ~ viewing in a browser and hosted in a browser are two different things ...

Comment: @drachenstern, of course your right, sorry Jeff