# How to license applications?

Tags: support, .net, c++

I registered on http://stackapps.com few days ago. I have written several applications that I want to place on this site. But I have a question -- how can I license my applications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This post](https://stackapps.com/questions/7/how-to-list-your-application-library-wrapper-script-here) contains all the information necessary to place your application here. If you check suggested template, you'll find a dedicated section for license information.
You don't need to do anything else regarding license, except specifying it.

Comment: Yes I have check this post but I want to know how to get License ??? for example MIT License

Comment: @ViTo How to get license text? You can try wikipedia ([MIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License)) or just google it.

Comment: Ok If I get licence text and put it into my application ... It means that nobody else or redistribute it ??? am I write ???

Comment: @ViTo If license says something's not allowed, then nobody will be able (legally) to do that.

Comment: Ok it mean I simply passed licence text in my application and nobody can redistribute or change code of application !!! Thanks !!!

Comment: @ViTo Note, that MIT license actually _do_ allow redistribution (and a lot of other things)  If you don't want anybody to change your code, it might be easier to just not release it.

Comment: "just not release it" not release code you mean ?

Comment: @ViTo Yes. You can post an application, but not release its code. [This app](http://stackapps.com/questions/36/stackmobile-com-view-stackexchange-sites-on-your-smartphone) has closed sources, for example.