# Alternative to official app?

Tags: support, app-request, android

I started using the Stack exchange app, but realized it was abandoned and just plain sucks. Now that I abandoned it though, I really miss push notifications and having all 8 sites I'm active in one place.

I looked around, and found similar things, but none are valid for 2019 because they have only chat functionality, compatibility issues with newer Android version, or just no longer exist

I know most functionality is easily done through a mobile browser, but there are no notification (excluding email every so often but I get a lot of spam so I ignore it, and it isn't instant) and each site must be checked manually.

So my question is if there are any actively (updated in last six months or newer) stack exchange apps, that work in 2019? Anywhere?

They should be fully compatible with Android 8 or newer, and have at least most functionality of the mobile site (create/flag/delete/comment/vote with questions/answers)

Comment: Good luck but, realistically, your 2 options are: (A) somehow get the official app improved; (B) just muddle through with the mobile site -- perhaps augmented by userscripts and browser extensions. ... There are huge problems with trying to do a 3rd-party app, starting with API 2.3 being undocumented and several serious, unresolved bugs.  Nobody currently here has evidenced interest in such an endeavor; you'd probably have to hire a new programmer.

Comment: @BrockAdams Sadly, it looks like I'm one of the only devs on only Android. Go figure. Is the main app source available?

Comment: No, (most of) [the main app code is not available for free](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16054).  You can *try*, via back-channels,  to get SE to open-source or semi-open-source the code if they are not going to maintain it themselves.  Several of us would gladly help maintain the App, API, and docs.  But SE has resisted all such offers so far.

Comment: @BrockAdams well, let's keep trying