# Script to keep mobile-view active

Tags: app, discussion, script-request

As you probably know SE is moving to the responsive view on there website meaning everything will look like the desktop kinda. Same with mobile devices. I’m new to SE for about 20 days, and I like the mobile view even though it’s limited.

Question is can somebody write a script that Mimics mobile view so we can have it around longer?

I’m on mobile 100% of the time so if you could write the app for mobile it would be nice.

I’m on iOS all the time but I do have an Android phone.

Related questions

[Deprecating our mobile views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367609/1059647)

[Permanently Force Mobile View on Stack Exchange Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357475/1059647)

[How to switch back to mobile version after switching to desktop version?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214132/1059647)

Current fix as of now is:

1. Scroll to bottom of SE and disable responsive view
2. Enable mobile view

I was advised that mobile view this way might be around for another 6-8 weeks so that is nice but I want the app so it last longer.

Comment: That... Will probably not be easy to do :) And very hard to maintain because SE is likely to keep breaking things during their rework of the UI to make it "stretchy" (I am not sure I am ready to call the current state "responsive" yet). An interesting request nonetheless - can't promise any ETA (other than the usual 6 to 8) but will definitely take a peek at what's possible. As you can see, people [tried similar things](https://stackapps.com/q/36/78873) in the past, but methinks none are currently maintained (most likely due to the cost of keeping up with SE's tweaks/breaks/changes)

Comment: Thanks @OlegValter didn’t know that SE breaks things lol . Still new and learning

Comment: You'll learn they do in no time - just stay around for a while :) The hardest part of addressing this request would probably be exactly that - unless following the footsteps of Nathan and simply serving a completely different UI on from another domain.

Comment: There's also a slight problem of support for userscripts on mobile devices - I know there is a bit of an issue with finding a way to make things work on Chrome and Opera there since most projects are either dead or very outdated - do you use something already you could recommend as in "it still works" or just wondering if this is possible?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this?  The responsive design on mobile works so much better than the mobile site.